# GWT + OSX = SWT issues

Tags: eclipse, macos, gwt, jvm, swt

I'm new to GWT development and I'm putting myself through the paces with Google's tutorial but I'm getting errors:

> java[10574:80f] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
>   2009-11-06 15:27:38.769 java[10574:80f] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000

I checked my Java prefs and I have Java SE6 (64 bit) as the preferred JVM. I'm really not sure how to clear this up.

Answer (score 3):

I think gwt hosted mode only works in a 32 bit environment, as of gwt version 1.7.1. Try passing "-d32" as an argument to the jvm to tell java 6 to run in 32 bit mode. That seems to work for me in Eclipse 3.5, Gwt 1.7.1 in Snow Leopard.

If it still doesn't work, searching google for ["Leopard GWT d32"](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GPEA_enUS307US308&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Leopard+Gwt+d32) should turn up some articles that should help you troubleshoot more.

Answer (score 0):

This message just means that the GWT toolset has loaded the Mac Java AWT at some point, and when you do that in Eclipse or any other SWT application you will get this message.

For you it's harmless and isn't the result of anything that you did in your code.

Answer (score -1):

There's [an open issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=135) on GWT and 64-bit Java that's been around for a long time, and includes various workarounds that you may be able to get to work. GWT 2 (not yet released) doesn't use the same hosted mode, and so the GWT developers say it won't have this issue.

Comment: The bug you linked to is about 32/64-bit support on Linux. This question deals with Mac OS X, so it doesn't apply.