# JAVA SWT/AWT Eclipse Mac OSX Java Cocoa CompatibilityMode Enabled

Tags: java, cocoa, swing, swt, awt

I'm developing a fairly complex `Java` application mixing `Swing` and `SWT`. Whenever I start the application, this is the console output (and the app doesn't show up):

```
2012-12-19 12:45:45.359 java[3442:f07] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2012-12-19 12:45:45.360 java[3442:f07] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
```

I've followed many guides and tutorials setting:

1. `System.setProperty("com.apple.awt.CocoaComponent.CompatibilityMode", "false");`
2. `-XstartOnSecondThread`
3. `--launcher-on-secondThread`

Now I really don't have any clue. The only way to make my app working on `Mac OSX` is to `export the Eclipse project to a JAR executable`. Well, this is annoying. Can someone explain to me how to set those properties above? Are there any magic trick?

**EDIT**: I'm using:

```
OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.2 ,
Java 1.6u37 64bit,
SWT 4.2 cocoa x64,
Windows XP ,
Java 1.6u37 32bit,
SWT 4.2 32bit
```

Comment: What version of Eclipse?

Comment: Now i'm downloading Indigo ... hope this will solve the problem

Comment: Nope, it's not working with Indigo too

Comment: You're saying that you're *not* setting those properties when you run from Eclipse?  If you are setting them, how?

Comment: Edward, I set **CompatibilityMode false** like above (first line of code), I added **--launcher.secondThread** to eclipse.ini just before -vmargs , and tried **-XstartOnSecondThread** on Run as -> Configurations -> arguments ... I tried also **-XstartOnFirstThread** with no success. On Windows XP with Java 1.6u37 32bit and SWT 32bit is running well. Here I have OSX Mountain Lion with Eclipse Indigo cocoa x64 and SWT x64.

Comment: It would seem likely that you'll need to set this in your Run/Debug Configuration **after `-vmargs`**, setting this in `eclipse.ini` should have no effect.  I would think you would simply want `-vmargs -Dcom.apple.awt.CocoaComponent.CompatibilityMode=false -XstartOnFirstThread`.  You should not need `--launcher.secondThread` as that only affects the Swing launcher.  To my knowledge, there is no such thing as `-XstartOnSecondThread`.

Comment: Well, maybe is because of my flu but I'm a bit confused. In ’eclipse.ini’ I '-Dcom.apple.awt.CocoaComponent.CompatibilityMode=false -XstartOnFirstThread' right after '-vmargs'. That's all? Or do I need to set something else in 'Run configurations -> Arguments -> VM Arguments/Program arguments'? Thanks BTW

Comment: well, I put "...CompatibilityMode=false" and "-XstartOnFirstThread" under "Run configurations -> Arguments -> Program arguments" but still not working

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690219/gwt-osx-swt-issues

Comment: Yep, no help though ... thinking about JavaFX (but no Flash! :-( )

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I've had this issue several times, as I work in a Java shop where everyone uses Eclipse, and I'm an OS X user.</strike>

The fix is a little weird.

You need to remove your current JRE from the "Installed JREs" preference, and then add it again.  When you do so, make sure that you select "Standard JVM" and *not* "Mac OS X JVM".

Adding JREs is a little annoying, so take note of the "Location" path string before you do so.  You'll point it to the same place, just change the "Type" property.

So, my answer is wrong.  It's pertinent if you're doing Swing/AWT only, but humorously enough immediately after posting this I had to write an SWT_AWT boondoggle and I got the same error on my Mac, even with the above settings.  I suspect that it has to do with the differences between Swing/AWT and SWT regarding the event loop (SWT = bring your own, Swing = provided by JVM).  I also get the error in IntelliJ IDEA 12, so it can't just be an Eclipse issue.

Comment: I ended up using Netbeans which starts correctly the first time without adding anything. It's such a shame that a so called "multiplatform" language has so many problems when switching around from PC to Mac to GNU/Linux. :-(

Comment: @neo Agreed, but SWT != Java.  Java does a pretty good job of being cross-platform by itself, but SWT is highly dependent on native code and the quality of the bridge to it.  It's also not part of any official Java working spec, it's owned by the Eclipse foundation and was originally an IBM product.  Anything that relies on native libraries is going to be painful to deploy cross-platform.

Comment: Yep that's true, I'm thinking about porting to JavaFX. Doing so I can delete all of the Swing and SWT pieces. JavaFX has his own implementation of a webbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my Macbook, as I can see you're downloading the Eclipse Indigo, which is the best you can do. Juno has bugs and also is slow since it consumes more performance than previous releases. I think Indigo is the best option. I know Java is portable and multi-platform but after being working with apple devices I found some kind of incompatibilities with Java, I think not because of Java, but because of the iOS, that's why for me the best I could do was to install a virtual machine with Ubuntu. So you can try the same with the Linux distribution you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

i had a simular problem when i used a jar for generating graphs. je jar used swt which seem to be not compatible with OSX. If you have are using swt or have imported a jar using swt try deleting it and fiding an equivalent that uses awt